# Let's get critical: Jan 2014 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Astronomy Stack Exchange](http://astronomy.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Why is the interstellar medium so hot?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/964/why-is-the-interstellar-medium-so-hot)

**Net Score: 7** (Excellent: 7, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Does the radio signal decay when it travels through the intergalactic space?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/1031/does-the-radio-signal-decay-when-it-travels-through-the-intergalactic-space)

**Net Score: 6** (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [How does one determine the effective temperature of a star from its spectrum?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/1013/how-does-one-determine-the-effective-temperature-of-a-star-from-its-spectrum)

**Net Score: 5** (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Colossus telescope, trying to outsmart aliens?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/908/colossus-telescope-trying-to-outsmart-aliens)

**Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [How well can we in principle determine $T_{\textrm{eff}}$ of a star?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/997/how-well-can-we-in-principle-determine-t-textrmeff-of-a-star)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [How can I measure the mass of eclipsing binary stars?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/906/how-can-i-measure-the-mass-of-eclipsing-binary-stars)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 7, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Can moon set after being up when due north? (pseudo circumpolarity)](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/937/can-moon-set-after-being-up-when-due-north-pseudo-circumpolarity)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Stars at near break-up rotation rates](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/907/stars-at-near-break-up-rotation-rates)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Solar maximum and minimum](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/941/solar-maximum-and-minimum)

**Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 4)

---

- [Has life been discovered outside of Earth?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/1054/has-life-been-discovered-outside-of-earth)

**Net Score: -6** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 7)

---

Answer (score 4):

Here are my quick thoughts on the question in reverse-rated order:

- [Has life been discovered outside of Earth?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/1054/has-life-been-discovered-outside-of-earth)

  This is a question of broad interest with two answers.  The top-voted one is accurate, but too terse.  The second largely quotes Wikipedia with a bit of speculative commentary thrown in.  This could well become a [greatest hit](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/02/stack-exchanges-greatest-hits/), but it really doesn't add much to human knowledge beyond what the rest of the internet provides.
- [Solar maximum and minimum](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/941/solar-maximum-and-minimum)

  Super basic question about solar weather; Wikipedia-style answer.  Ho hum.
- [Stars at near break-up rotation rates](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/907/stars-at-near-break-up-rotation-rates)

  Very interesting question; expert answer.  So far so good.  The answer needs a friendly edit to help it be well-formatted and a little less chatty.  If someone else had taking the hints to read the paper or done some more digging, there might be a more definitive answer.  There's potential here, but it's untapped.
- [Can moon set after being up when due north? (pseudo circumpolarity)](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/937/can-moon-set-after-being-up-when-due-north-pseudo-circumpolarity)

  A much better question with two solid answers.  This is what I think of when I contemplate an Astronomy Q&A site.  Additionally, it turns up as a top Google result (or number two) for the terms I used to search for the answer.  I could see some niggles with the question, but overall, this is an Excellent question.
- [How can I measure the mass of eclipsing binary stars?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/906/how-can-i-measure-the-mass-of-eclipsing-binary-stars)

  Probably an overly-broad question.  But the answer seems solid though it doesn't mention the binary star wrinkle, which makes me wonder if it answers a slightly different question.
- [How well can we in principle determine $T_{\textrm{eff}}$ of a star?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/997/how-well-can-we-in-principle-determine-t-textrmeff-of-a-star)

  Clearly an interesting question with a knowledgeable answerer.  But it sure seems like the comments should be rolled into the text of the answer somehow.  Also, the asker seems to be left unsatisfied.
- [Colossus telescope, trying to outsmart aliens?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/908/colossus-telescope-trying-to-outsmart-aliens)

  Just barely makes the first page of results when Googling "[colossus telescope](https://www.google.com/search?q=colossus+telescope)".  Add "[hide](https://www.google.com/search?q=colossus+telescope+hide)" and its a top result.  Other results don't seem to answer the question, so this is another Excellent in my book.
- [How does one determine the effective temperature of a star from its spectrum?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/1013/how-does-one-determine-the-effective-temperature-of-a-star-from-its-spectrum)

  A basic question, but a really good answer.  The search space is too crowded for the question to show up on the first page of a search, however. All in all: Satisfactory.
- [Does the radio signal decay when it travels through the intergalactic space?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/1031/does-the-radio-signal-decay-when-it-travels-through-the-intergalactic-space)

  Another basic question/good answer situation.  This time, this site makes the first page of Google.  I'd say the three Wikipedia results are likely better places to read up on this, but the Yahoo Answers and forums are worse.  If the question were a bit more specific, I'd say it's Excellent.  As is, Satisfactory.
- [Why is the interstellar medium so hot?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/964/why-is-the-interstellar-medium-so-hot)

  Good question + good answer + lots of other search results = Satisfactory.

Overall, there's a lot to like about this site.  But it's still in the stage where too many questions are easy and too many answers are heavily cribbed from Wikipedia.  We've made it out of private beta, but the call remains:

> [Let's ask more meaty questions!](https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59/lets-ask-more-meaty-questions)

Answer (score 3):

My two cents: we may have a lot of improvement to be done to make our Q&A better, but lately we have had a lot more visitors and a lot more posts with a solid curiosity for diverse and interesting topics. I think the site is doing well and will continue to do better; especially if we strive to improve where we can.

Answer (score 2):

It seemed to me that questions that appeared in this evaluation where mostly very good as were their answers. I know that not all of them are, I wonder if they were chosen randomly.

Comment: I found very few to be above satisfactory, though. There is definitely a lot of improvement to be done.

Comment: They are chosen randomly from recent, open questions with at least one answer.